# Accuracy Openweathermap or is it the Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, location, openweathermap

I'm building a weather app for Apple Watch only and the app is working. The strange thing is that I think that the coordinates that Openweathermap is using are not accurate.

I live in a small town in The Netherlands and that is recognised when I type it in on the website of Openweathermap. It returns also the coordinates on this website with 4 decimal places for the latitude and three decimal places for the longitude.

I generate the URL with coordinates, this results in a long number (I've printed this to the console) and the return is much shorter.

These coordinates are the real coordinates of my city, when I compare it to the coordinates from this website: https://www.where-am-i.net are those the same that my app is showing. The code I'm using is:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

Changing to:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```

(this is not recommended unless device is plugged in)

With other words, does anyone know why the coordinates of openweathermap are different from the real coordinates and is there a solution for this. Because the app is now giving an other name back for the city that I'm located in.

The only thing I can think of is is dat my city is not recognised by open weather, but based on the location it will get de weather for the location with their coordinates, but will keep the city name in place. The outcome is the same.

Comment: How large is the difference?

Comment: The difference in the latitude is 0.22 and in the longitude 0.2. I think that open weather does not have my city with coordinates in their database, but a bigger area. The display name is the township, and not the city in the township.